# Hubspot Custom Module for RSS Parsing in Emails

Tags: email, rss, hubspot

Hubspot's native RSS parsing is very limited. However, Hubspot allows for custom modules to be created.

I'm looking for a way to build my own RSS parser in Hubspot to insert RSS content into emails.

Comment: http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/hubl-supported-modules#rss-listing

Comment: Thanks @TimJoyce, but that module only support plain-text output. I need to return the full html content from the RSS item description.